# Error :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) in web api for provider hosted app

Tags: api, sharepoint, model-view-controller

I have created one provider hosted app and in that I have used api controller, in that I have written one method named as GetTest.
When I try to call it from JavaScript it is giving me error as "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this : [Troubleshooting HTTP 405 Errors after Publishing Web API 2 Applications](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications)

OR

Add this attribute your method name **[AcceptVerbs("GET")]**